# Bootstrap aggregation (bagging) of logistic regression classifiers

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, bootstrap, bagging

So I'm taking N bootstrap samples and training N logistic regression classifiers on these samples. Each classifier gives me some probability of being in a binary class and then I average these N probabilities to get a final prediction.

My question is if I took the N sets of regression coefficients and averaged those and used that averaged set of coefficients in a logistic regression classifier and took the output probability as the final prediction, is this the same as taking the average of the resultant N probabilities as described in the previous paragraph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but the weighted sum of the coefficients should be the weighted sum of the individual log-odds ratio calculated for each sample.

Consider the equation for g(x) on [the Wikipedia page on logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Logistic_function.2C_odds_ratio.2C_and_logit). Since $g(x) = \ln{(\pi_x/(1-\pi_x))} = {\bf \beta} x + \beta_0$, the weighted average of $g(x)$'s computed over multiple samples should be equal to the weighted average of the coefficients. So, if you average the coefficients ($\beta$s), you should get the mean log odds ratio across all your classifiers. You can calculate the mean odds ratio and mean probability from there.

Comment: Hmm right that makes sense. So if I wanted to come up with a single logistic regression model that is equivalent to the average of the output from these N bootstraps (i.e. a single set of regression coefficients) how would I do that?

Comment: When you do logistic regression, you are essentially doing a linear regression on the log-odds ratio. If you are running a linear regression on multiple samples from the same dataset, you should treat the mean of the calculated coefficients as the coefficients for your model. Taking the average of the probabilities is hard to justify. PS: I deleted my previous comment as it was confusing.